# c# Regex Question "Find SQL Template Parameter in string"

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse a SQL String and look for SQL Template Parameter formatted strings.  i.e. < Name, Type, Value>.  I am parsing that data out to a Dictionary<String, Object>.  I am not an expert in Regex, but this appears to be the best way to find the specific format, I just cannot seem to wrap my head around the Regex command I am looking for.

```
<.+?>
```

Will get me the Template Parameters I am looking for, but also catches part of a common Where statement of

```
WHERE (Column < value) or (column > value2)
```

What would be the Regex command to find all instances of "<string,string,stringornumber>" everything I tried fails to find anything, so I am sure I am just not fully grasping Regex for some reason today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you, this is a javascript example but you can change it to C#, if you need to account for other characters besides **a-zA-Z0-9@_** then just add those characters into the bracket expressions:

```js
const mysql = 'select <@test, int,  10>, <@test2, bigint, 1200000000000> from mytable where (col1 < @test) or (col1 > @test2)';
const matches = mysql.match(/<[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+?,\s*?[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+?,\s*?[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+>/g);
for(let a = 0; a < matches.length; a++){
   console.log(matches[a]);
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a C# Example:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("<[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+?,\\s*?[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+?,\\s*?[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+>", RegexOptions.Multiline);        
string test = "select <@test, int,  10>, <@test2, bigint, 1200000000000> from mytable where (col1 < @test) or (col1 > @test2)";
MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(test);
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: So, I see someone downvoted this. Want to explain why? Or are you just going through and down voting people?

Answer (score 1):

For a broad match, you can match non whitespace characters except `,` `<` `>` using a negated character class:

```
<(?:[^\s<>,]+\s*,\s*){2}[^\s<>,]+>
```

The pattern matches:

- `<` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\s<>,]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `<` `>` and `,`
  - `\s*,\s*` Match a comma between optional whitespace chars
- `){2}` Close the non capture group and repeat 2 times
- `[^\s<>,]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `<` `>` and `,`
- `>` Match literally

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sxflWA/1).

---

If only the first value can start with an @ you can make the pattern stricter and start with match with @ and 1 or more word characters `\w+` and only word characters for the 2nd and 3rd value:

```
<@\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/00HVU8/1)